# How can we use @Query for joining the documents among multiple collections of mongodb in spring data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

how can we join the collections based on the referenced documents @DBRef by using @Query in spring data mongodb?

@Query("{ 'name' : ?0 }")
List findUsersByName(String name);
this is for simple query, but i need same with joining of multiple collections of mongodb?

Comment: For connecting multiple collections like join or lookup?

Comment: It is not possible using @Query - annotation. Aggregations and other operations are not supported using that annotation.
You have to write custom Implementation class of your repository and then write the methods you need.
https://xpadro.com/2016/04/data-aggregation-with-spring-data-mongodb-and-spring-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to join multiple collections like populate and lookup.

For Populate

```
Loans.find({
    timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date(dates.startdate),
        $lte: new Date(dates.enddate)
    }
})
    .select('timestamp userId')
    .populate('userId', 'doj')
    .exec(function(err, result) {
         console.log(result)
    })
```

For lookup

```
  var aggregate = [
    {
      $match: {
        _disbursed: true
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "lenderId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "lender"
      }
    }
]

  Loans.aggregate(aggregate, function(err, result) {

    console.log(result)
  });
```

Comment: I think this is in the Mongodb Client, but I need the query in Repository class of a spring boot application to get the data from multiple collections